# Next.js: element won't inherit global class with same classname

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I've searched a while for this issue but didn't find anything and it's driving me crazy.
I'm using Next.js to develop an application, now I have weird bug and don't know where it comes from. 
When I import my stylesheet as a global one in _app.js, it just appears in the head without any issue.
The weird point is the moment when the elements come in. There I have a `<div>` with the correct class but somehow the element doesn't inherit the css for that class.
Has someone else experienced this?

UPDATE:
Found the cause! For some reason, next.js renders `@charset "UTF-8";` on top of that css block. Any idea why it does that?

Thanks in advance

**Styles in head of the file**

[image: Styles in Head of image]

**Elements in the file**

[image]

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this?

Comment: adding this to a sandbox would make it a lot of work, The weird part is that in my 'components' folder I have 'wapp' and 'webshop' as folders and de scss style files for all components in wapp are working perfect, but all the scss files in webshop components wont adapt the styling

Comment: Okay just found the reason, when rendering it adds ```@charset "UTF-8";``` for some reason. Do you know why